# Increment cell value in spreadsheet Google Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to increment the value in the `A1` cell.

```
function increment(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

   var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
   cellValue = cell.getValue("A1");
   cell.SetValue(cellValue + 1);
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling `getValue()` with an argument. This function does not take any arguments, as can be seen in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()

```
  function increment(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

   var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
   //Returns the value of the top-left cell in the sheet
   var value = range.getValue();
   range.setValue(value + 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks i used this code and it works
function increment(){
 
  var ssRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1');
  //obtenir la valeur de la cellule A1
  var value = ssRange.getValue();
  //if statement to check value in A1 and if it is null, undefined, false, 0, NAN
if (!value) {
 //si la cellule est vide afficher 0
  
  var setCell = ssRange.setValue(0);
}
 //incrémenter par 1 la valeur de la celule
else {
  var updateCell = ssRange.setValue(value + 1);  
}
}